# How to handle image content display in responsive website?

Tags: wordpress, html, content-management-system, responsive, responsive-images

I'm working in a project of building a responsive website. The painful thing we're having is to deal with the content of the image in different display modes. Please be noted: **the image content**.

The thing is: in almost pages at PC view, the images are displayed in landscape, with great ratio between width and height. Now when bringing them to mobile view, we have to display it in a different frame. And as you might imagine, now the content of the image was scaled and cropped and then exported to some very weird images on mobile view. Like a wide picture with people are almost in left side, but after being cropped there are only non-sense objects in the picture left.

IMHO, via technical solutions we are only processing the technical attributes of the image (resizing, scaling), we are unable to deal with the image content, that's really a human matter, right?

I'm thinking about 4 solutions:

- 1 - Despite the customer feelings, we just scale the picture (keep
  all content, just resizing it). The output sometimes will be very
  ridiculous I guess because of resizing a landscape picture to a
  portrait or square one. But that's mostly the easiest way to come up.
- 2 - Considering to image frame size on mobile view, and auto crop the
  picture by picking the center area of the picture. As I said above,
  it produced the non-sense picture after all.
- 3 - Informing customer, whenever they upload a picture, they have to upload 2 copies of it, 1 for desktop view and 1 for mobile view, and they're definitely responsible for the content displaying at front side. Tons of effort need to be spent by customers, but easier for development.
- 4 - Advanced feature: user can upload only 1 picture, we provide the
  different view-ports and a cropper for them to decide how the image
  displays on those after being cropped.

I don't have much experience in dealing with these stuff, and not sure how the world out there handling this case. As I see for now Wordpress is only requiring users to upload only 1 picture and it will automatically scale it (my 1st option). Does anyone have experience on this? Can you please share me your solutions and also your thoughts about my above solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a simple web application for them to upload the picture and provide your client with a preview of how the pictures with look like for both desktop and mobile.  in php, there is the GD library and it is quite easy to use for cropping and resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the 4th and the 1st option so you don't have to deal with it,
Crop and scale with the options you have AND let the customer decide if they want to change it and choose how the image is been displayed.
in case they ask you can say they have the option to fix it, in case they don't want to you already handle the best technological option.